# how to replace group-focus with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css, hamburger-menu

I am trying to replace `group-focus` with `React` state `isOpen`.

[Icon number 7](https://codepen.io/farnous/details/abEbwMd)

I tried to just simple replace whenever `group-focus` is to conditional rendering. But the X is not shown

This is my actuall code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function HamburgerIcon() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`relative group ${isOpen ? "focus:ring-4" : ""}`} onClick={toggleMenu}>
        <div className={`relative
         flex 
         overflow-hidden
         items-center
        justify-center 
        rounded-full 
        w-[50px] 
        h-[50px] 
        transform 
        transition-all
        ring-0 
        ring-secondary 
        hover:ring-8 duration-200 shadow-md ${isOpen ? "ring-4" : ""}`}>
          <div className={`flex flex-col justify-between w-[20px] h-[20px] transform transition-all duration-300 origin-center overflow-hidden`}>
            {/*This is div as Hamburger */}
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 transform transition-all duration-300 origin-left ${isOpen ? "rotate-45 translate-y-6 delay-100" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 rounded transform transition-all duration-300 ${isOpen ? "translate-y-6 delay-75" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 transform transition-all duration-300 origin-left ${isOpen ? "translate-y-6" : ""}`}></div>

            {/*This is div with X*/}
            <div className={`absolute items-center justify-between transform transition-all duration-500 top-2.5 ${isOpen ? "-translate-x-10" : "translate-x-0"} flex w-0 ${isOpen ? "w-12" : ""}`}>
              <div className={`absolute bg-font-color h-[2px] w-5 transform transition-all duration-500 ${isOpen ? "rotate-45 delay-300" : ""}`}></div>
              <div className={`absolute bg-font-color h-[2px] w-5 transform transition-all duration-500 ${isOpen ? "-rotate-45 delay-300" : ""}`}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if I click on button the X is not shown is not displayed, or is displayed at the same time as the hamburger and therefore looks like it is not displayed at all

[image: The output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conditional the wrong way around.

In the example CodePen:

```html
<div class="… -translate-x-10 group-focus:translate-x-0 …">
```

But in your JSX code:

```
<div className={`… ${isOpen ? "-translate-x-10" : "translate-x-0"} …`}>
```

Whereas it should be:

```
<div className={`… ${isOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "-translate-x-10"} …`}>
```

Full code:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'font-color': 'red',
      },
    },
  },
};

const { useState } = React;

function HamburgerIcon() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`relative group ${isOpen ? "focus:ring-4" : ""}`} onClick={toggleMenu}>
        <div className={`relative flex  overflow-hidden items-center justify-center  rounded-full  w-[50px]  h-[50px]  transform  transition-all ring-0  ring-secondary  hover:ring-8 duration-200 shadow-md ${isOpen ? "ring-4" : ""}`}>
          <div className={`flex flex-col justify-between w-[20px] h-[20px] transform transition-all duration-300 origin-center overflow-hidden`}>
            {/*This is div as Hamburger */}
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 transform transition-all duration-300 origin-left ${isOpen ? "rotate-45 translate-y-6 delay-100" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 rounded transform transition-all duration-300 ${isOpen ? "translate-y-6 delay-75" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`bg-font-color h-[2px] w-7 transform transition-all duration-300 origin-left ${isOpen ? "translate-y-6" : ""}`}></div>

            {/*This is div with X*/}
            <div className={`absolute items-center justify-between transform transition-all duration-500 top-2.5 ${isOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "-translate-x-10"} flex w-0 ${isOpen ? "w-12" : ""}`}>
              <div className={`absolute bg-font-color h-[2px] w-5 transform transition-all duration-500 ${isOpen ? "rotate-45 delay-300" : ""}`}></div>
              <div className={`absolute bg-font-color h-[2px] w-5 transform transition-all duration-500 ${isOpen ? "-rotate-45 delay-300" : ""}`}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<HamburgerIcon/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```